# How to solve jquery error in mobile/tablet devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

A couple of days i found an issue that my jquery wasn't responding on ios devices. Now i found what the problem was. It was a perfect working code. Now i thought i will not include this on mobile so i used this code

```
 This is the code:
   if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) === false ) {
    var muziek = getCookie("Muziek");

      // Save progression when leaving window
       window.onbeforeunload = () => {
           var prog = $('#muziek audio')[0].currentTime;
           console.log("current time = ", prog);
           sessionStorage.setItem('audioProgression', prog);
           };
       }
```

I test this on the google element inspector on the different sizes and it worked. But on my ipad it still doesn't, is there a way i can use this code to run and not block the jquery on my ios device? I do not need the music in the ios devices or other mobile/tablet devices. But i still need it on my computer browser. Does anybody know a way i can solve this?

Kind regards
Dylan

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/3168859) helps you

Comment: @Dekel Since i do not have an apple computer i can't check the inspector on my ipad. On normal browsers it doesn't give an error so i have no clue why it is not working. Maybe splitting it up in a different javascript file might work?

Comment: How do you know there is an error, and how do you know the error is there?

Comment: @Dekel because my jquery isn't loading in on ios devices. On all others it will load but not on IOS when i use that code above.